# How do I write basic Doubly Linked List functions in Java?

Tags: java

My first assignment in my programming class is about writing code for a Doubly Linked List, which includes writing an add, remove, size, iterator first, iterator last, and iterator find functions.  I have spent 3 hours and gotten no where in understanding this.  I understand what happens if I can see it in a picture.  But my problem is translating it to code.  This is what I have so far:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList< G > {

    public class node {
        G data;
        node next;
        node prev;
        public node(G data, node next, node prev) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
    node header;
    node footer;


    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        header = new node(null, null, null);
        footer = new node(null, header, null);
        header.next = footer;
    }

    public void add(G data) {
        header.next = new node(data, footer.prev, footer);  
    }

    public int size() {
        node current = header.next;
        int quanity = 0;
        if (current == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        while (current != null) {
            current = current.next;
            quanity++;
        }
        return quanity;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        DoublyLinkedList<Integer> test = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
        //test.add(new Integer(2));
        //test.add(new Integer(22));
        //test.add(new Integer(222));

            System.out.println(test.size());

    }
}
```

As you can see, I've been using the main() to test everything.  From what I've been told by my teacher, my constructor and node class look fine.  However I know either my add and size are not right because when I test this, when there is no nodes in the list, it displays nothing, but it should display 0 right?  I mean, assuming my size code is right, which I'm not sure of.

And whenever I add a node, no matter how many I add, it always displays 1.  So either both add and size are broken, or both are.  I have not written the other functions as it makes no sense until I figure these ones out.  Please someone help me understand this!  Thank you.

Comment: Time to get acquainted with a debugger.

Comment: 1) reexamine your `add()` method, work through the references after you add a couple thing to the list  by hand 2) its easier to have a `size` field that updates each time you add versus recalcultaing

Answer (score 1):

Declare a `size` field in `DoublyLinkedList` to store the current size of the list. When `add` succeed, make `size++`. When `remove` succeed, make `size--`. And `size()` method just simply return the value of `size`.

The sample code is here:

```
    private int size = 0;

    public void add(G data) {
        header.next = new node(data, footer.prev, footer);
        size++;
    }
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
```

Comment: WoW!!! thats very smart and easy!!! Thank you so much!!! The test seems to work great!!!  I understand why that code is better and much simpler!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Noticed couple of things:

First, footer is not constructed correctly. It should be:

```
public DoublyLinkedList() {
  ..
  footer = new node(null, null, header);
  // your code is incorrectly creating a circular list
  ..
  }
```

Secondly add() method doesn't look correct. It should be something like :

```
public void add(G data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data, header, null);  
    header.prev = newNode
    header = newNode;
}
```

// for adding at the front (LIFO)

OR

```
public void add(G data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data, null, footer);  
    footer.next = newNode
    footer = newNode;
}
```

//for adding at the tail (FIFO)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [wikipedia entry for doubly linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list).  It has some good pseudo code.

Using your own code I'm going to make a few suggestions

```
public class DoublyLinkedList< G > {

    public class node {
    G data;
    node next;
    node prev;
    public node(G data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    }
    }
    node header;
    node footer;


    public DoublyLinkedList() {
    header = new node(null);
    footer = new node(null);
    header.next = footer;//link the header to the footer
    footer.prev = header;//link the footer to the header
    }

    public void add(G data) { //assuming you are adding the node to the head of the list
    node newNode = new node(data); //creating new node to add with the data
    newNode.next = header.next; // setting new node to head of the list or the footer
    newNode.prev = header; //setting the new node's previous node to the header
    header.next = newNode; //setting the newNode as the next node.
    }

    public int size() {
    node current = header.next;
    int quantity = 0;
    if (current.data == null/*Empty list*/) { //you needed to specify what you were trying to test
        return 0;
    }
    while (current.data != null/*traversing the list*/) { 
        current = current.next;
        quantity++;
    }
    return quantity;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    DoublyLinkedList<Integer> test = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
    //test.add(new Integer(2));
    //test.add(new Integer(22));
    //test.add(new Integer(222));

        System.out.println(test.size());

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {
private class Node {
    String value;
    Node next,prev;

    public Node(String val, Node n, Node p) {
        value = val;
        next = n;
        prev=p;
    }

    Node(String val) {
        this(val, null, null);
    }
}
private Node first;
private Node last;

public DoublyLinkedList() {
    first = null;
    last = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return first==null;
}
public int size(){
    int count=0;
    Node p=first;
    while(p!=null){
        count++;
        p=p.next;
    }
    return count;
}
public void add(String e) {

    if(isEmpty()){
        last=new Node(e);
        first=last;
    }
    else{
        last.next=new Node(e, null, last);
        last=last.next;
    }
}
public void add(int index, String e){
    if(index<0||index>size()){
        String message=String.valueOf(index);
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(message);
    }
    if(index==0){
        Node p=first;
        first=new Node(e,p,null);
        if(p!=null)
            p.prev=first;
        if(last==null)
            last=first;
        return;
    }
    Node pred=first;
    for(int k=1; k<=index-1;k++){
        pred=pred.next;
    }
    Node succ=pred.next;
    Node middle=new Node(e,succ,pred);
    pred.next=middle;
    if(succ==null)
        last=middle;
    else
        succ.prev=middle;
}
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder strBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    Node p=first;
    while(p!=null){
        strBuilder.append(p.value+"\n");
        p=p.next;
    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
}
public String remove(int index){
    if(index<0||index>=size()){
        String message=String.valueOf(index);
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(message);
    }
    Node target=first;
    for(int k=1; k<=index;k++){
        target=target.next;
    }
    String element=target.value;
    Node pred=target.prev;
    Node succ=target.next;
    if(pred==null)
        first=succ;
    else
        pred.next=succ;
    if(succ==null)
        last=pred;
    else
        succ.prev=pred;
    return element;
}
public boolean remove(String element){
    if(isEmpty())
        return false;
    Node target=first;
    while(target!=null&&!element.equals(target.value))
        target=target.next;
    if(target==null)
        return false;
    Node pred=target.prev;
    Node succ=target.next;
    if(pred==null)
        first=succ;
    else
        pred.next=succ;
    if(succ==null)
        last=pred;
    else
        succ.prev=pred;
    return true;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    DoublyLinkedList list1=new DoublyLinkedList();
    String[] array={"a","c","e","f"};
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        list1.add(array[i]);
    }
    list1.add(1,"b");
    list1.add(3,"d");
    System.out.println(list1);

}


}
```

Comment: Answer isn't really useful, especially to a beginner, unless you explain.

Comment: The code is pretty much self-explanatory. I don't think it requires any further explanation. Can't help if you are not conceptually clear about your data structures.

Comment: @user10561 If the op was 100% conceptually clear they wouldn't have asked the question in the first place

Comment: @vandale The questionnaire is absolutely clear about his concepts. All that he is asking is for implementing his ideas in code form.